# nilpotent groups of automorphisms (don't understand a step in the proof)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can someone perhaps help me to understand a step in the following proof:

[image]

continuing on the next page...

[image]

It's the transition between the two pages which I don't understand. It might be possible that I am missing out on some basic properties of $Hol(G)$, though.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well, by definition
\begin{equation}
\Phi_{j} = \{ a \in \Phi : [G_{i}, a] \subseteq G_{i+j}\ \text{for all $i$} \}.
\end{equation}
So to verify that
\begin{equation}
[\Phi_{j} , \Phi] \subseteq \Phi_{j+1}
\end{equation}
for all $j$, you have to show that 
\begin{equation}
[G_{i}, [\Phi_{j} , \Phi]] \subseteq G_{i + j + 1}
\end{equation}
for all $i, j$.

Comment: Thanks. It might help me if one perhaps could write down an element of the commutator explictly. The notion of Hol and semi-direct product was some missing background. I tried to fill this up myself, but it still seems to cause some problems. 

If I am right, a typical element of $[G_i, a]$ looks like:

$$(g, id)^{-1} \cdot (e,a)^{-1} \cdot (g, id) \cdot (e,a) = (g^{-1},id) \cdot (e,a^{-1}) \cdot (g, id) \cdot (e,a) = (g^{-1}, a^{-1}) \cdot (g, id) \cdot (e,a) = (g^{-1} a^{-1}(g), a^{-1}) \cdot (e,a) = (g^{-1} a^{-1}(g), id)$$

Comment: I think you should avoid an excess of notation, for the sake of clarity. I think a good approach is to think of the semidirect product of $G$ and $\Phi$ as the group $S$ defined (up to isomorphism) by these properties: $S = G \Phi$, $G \cap \Phi = 1$, and an element $a \in \Phi$ act by conjugation on an element $g$ of $G$ by $a^{-1} g a = g^a$, where $g^a$ denotes the action of the automorphism $a$ on $g$ (in particular, $G$ is normal in $S$). Then your commutator is simply $g^{-1} a^{-1} g a = g^{-1} g^a$.